# LeafletJS map click event not caught when using ScalaJS + Akka

Tags: leaflet, akka, scala.js

I'm working on a ScalaJS + Akka web app that displays a map using LeafletJS.  This all works fine except when I try to catch the LeafletJS map's `click` event.

Creating the map and adding the tile layer all work nicely:

```
def worldMap(mapDiv: String): LMap = {
  // Show map of whole world
  val mapRef = L.map(mapDiv, LMapOptions.zoom(worldZoomLevel).center(startPos))

  // Add click event handler to map
  mapRef.on("click", (msg: dom.MouseEvent) => StageManager.countryMapActor ! msg)

  val queryStr = (
    for (p <- mbQueryParams.keys)
      yield s"$p=${mbQueryParams.get(p).get}"
    ).mkString("?", "&", "")

  // Add map tile layer
  L.tileLayer(
    mapBoxEndpoint + queryStr,
    TileLayerOptions.
      id("mapbox.streets").
      maxZoom(19).
      attribution(
        """Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors,
          |<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>,
          |Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>""".stripMargin)
  ).addTo(mapRef)

  mapRef
}
```

The line of code saying

```
mapRef.on("click", (msg: MouseEvent) => StageManager.countryMapActor ! msg)
```

compiles and runs fine, but the corresponding Akka actor that listens for this event is never called.

The actor that listens for this event contains the following:

```
class CountryMapActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    // SNIP
    case evt: MouseEvent =>
      if (evt.hasOwnProperty("latlng")) {
        // do something with lat/lng...
      }
  }
}
```

But this message is never received - irrespective of whether I use `dom.Event` or `dom.MouseEvent`.

I've tried changing the event type to `LeafletMouseEvent` (as per the [leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#event-objects)), but then the `receive` method in above the actor fails to compile with the error message `isInstanceOf[com.felstar.scalajs.leaflet.LeafletMouseEvent] not supported because it is a raw JS trait`

I don't want to add a marker to the map because the whole point is that the user can click anywhere on the map to retrieve information about that location.

Any ideas how to get a LeafletJS map click event to work through ScalaJS?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it...

First, in order to be able to extract the relevant geographic information, the click event handler function added to the Map object must take a parameter of type `LeafletMouseEvent`.

The event name is `click` which can either be hardcoded, or to be more robust, obtained using `LMapEvent.click.toString`.

```
mapRef.on(LMapEvent.click.toString, (evt: LeafletMouseEvent) =>
  StageManager.countryMapActor ! MessageBox.MapClick(new MapLocation(evt.latlng))
)
```

Secondly, the event object of type `LeafletMouseEvent` cannot be sent directly as a message to the Akka actor because it is just a trait. 
 Hence the relevant data must first be unloaded from the event object into an instance of some concrete class (in my case, I just made up something called `MapLocation`)

```
class MapLocation(latlng: leaflet.LatLng) {
  val lat:Double = latlng.lat
  val lng:Double = latlng.lng
}
```

Finally, the Akka actor listening for this message receives a message of type `MapLocation`, not a message of some event type.  In my case, all the messages used by the various actors are defined as a set of case classes in an object called `MessageBox`; hence in the above code, I'm sending a message of type `MessageBox.MapClick(new MapLocation(evt.latlng))`

All works now...

BTW, the LeafletJS façcade I'm using is provided by [Dino Fancellu](https://github.com/fancellu/scalajs-leaflet)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the event name should be `"click"` instead of `"onclick"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried using the event name `click` and it doesn't have any effect.  I'll edit the original post to reflect this.